# creating a string joining the keys of a hashmap in rust

Tags: rust

How can a create a string joining all keys of a hashmap in rust and adding a separator among each of them? I am very new to rust.

In python it would be something like this:

`>>> ', '.join({'a':'x', 'b':'y'}.keys())
'a, b'`

Comment: iter over keys, then use the duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rust, `HashMap`s are not ordered, so the actual order of the keys in the `String` will be undefined.

If that is not a problem, you could do it like this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

let mut hm = HashMap::new();

hm.insert("a", ());
hm.insert("b", ());
hm.insert("c", ());
hm.insert("d", ());
hm.insert("e", ());

let s = hm.keys().map(|s| &**s).collect::<Vec<_>>().join(", ");
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=609816993c20b5e9b9c1dcb352fe3de1)